# Fitting html content into a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg, frontend

I'm developing several dashboard components using html. (e.g table, svg elements etc.)

I don't want to specify dimension (width, height) of these components as I reuse them later in other components.

I'd like to have these components fit into the divs that contain them.

Let's assume that I have a pie chart developed with svg circle element, or a table that uses table tag in html and I want these components to fill the div that contains them.

Is there any way to specify dimensions of these elements in terms of percentage ?

Note: In the following code , ReactJS is used , but the idea is same.

Code :

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <svg>
                <g>
                    {this.props.children}
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

Now I want to pass an element to this div as this.props.children , but I don't want to specify any size for that element. I'd like to specify it in the wrapping div element with use of Bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have something in Codepen or JSfiddle that illustrates the dilemma?

Comment: Better yet, post a code example in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper { position:relative }
.wrapper > * { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100% }
```

Then add a `viewBox` attribute on your SVG to specify which content within it should fill the region and scale to fit.